# The limits of the gamma function

Tags: limits, gamma-function

Let 
$$g(m)=\frac{\left[\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{m})\right]^2}{\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{m})},$$
how to consider the limit of $g(m)$ when $m\rightarrow 0^+$ ?If the limit exsits ,calculate it.

Comment: Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\displaystyle \Gamma(1+x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^x}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)}$ one gets $\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma(1+x)^2}{\Gamma(1+2x)}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\left(\frac{x}{k+x}\right)^2\right)$ .

Then $x\to\infty$ .

You can also use $\displaystyle 0<\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\leq\frac{1}{2^n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which is easier to proof (e.g. induction).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use another way to prove that $\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow 0} g(m) = 0^+$,that is Legendre Duplication Formula $$\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2s)=2^{2s-1}\Gamma(s)\Gamma(s+\frac{1}{2})$$.But how can I understand the thought you provided?

Comment: @Linxiaodiu : The inequality can be shown easily (left side is trivial and right side by induction) and shows that $\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\to 0$ for $n\to \infty\enspace$ (and $n\to\infty$ is here equivalent to $m\to 0$, e.g. $m:=\frac{1}{n}$) .

Comment: Again thanks for your  patience.Since $g(m)$ is a continuous function,I think using the following inequality $$\frac{\Gamma^2(1+n)}{\Gamma(1+2(n+1))} <\frac{\Gamma^2(1+\frac{1}{m})}{\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{m})} < \frac{\Gamma^2(1+n+1)}{\Gamma(1+2n)} $$ to prove it seems better,for any $m>0$small enough,there exists $n$ satisfied $$\frac{1}{n+1}< m < \frac{1}{n}$$